# What does LM25KD mean?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, metallurgy

I did some reasearch. It looks like LM25 refers to a specific aluminum alloy. I think the KD refers to something about how it is finished.

The context is this sentence describing the wheels of one of my cars from the shop manual:

> The wheels are four bold locating aluminum alloy LM25KD with 45 ribs equally spaced at 8º, with windows between.

I am just curious what the KD means and how I might look something like that up.

Comment: probably dependent on the manufacturer

Comment: I guess I will never know. 